# Применение метода Вегстейна

Tags: c, математика, численные-методы

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
double f(double x)
{
    return (x*x)*log10(x)-3.8;
}
double psi(double x, double *x1)
{
     double h=(*x1-x);
    *x1=x;
    return -1*h/(f(x+h)-f(x));
}
int main()
{
    double x,x1,p;
    double eps;
    int mt,i;
    double delta;
    printf ("Vvedite: x0, xl, epsilon, max itexation\n");
    scanf("%lf",&x);
    scanf("%lf",&x1);
    scanf("%lf",eps);
    scanf("%d",&mt);
    for(i=1; i<=mt;i++)
    {
        p=psi(x,&x1);
        if(p==0.0)
        {
            printf("Error,psi(x)=0!\n");
        }
        delta=f(x)*p;
        x=x+delta;
        printf("x=%lf\n",x);
        if(fabs(delta)<eps)break;
    }
    if(i>=mt)
    {
        printf("Error max iterations\n");
    }
printf("x=%lf \n",x);
printf("f(x)=%lf",f(x));
}
```

Comment: Добавьте, какие данные вводите, что выводит программа, и что вы ожидали получить.

Comment: И что это - `scanf("%lf",eps);`- прошло?...

Comment: @Harry Только заметил эту ошибку в коде, спасибо

Comment: Так вас устроило мое решение, нет?

Comment: @Harry Да, спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Легкое ощущение, что мы понимаем под [методом Вегстейна](https://studfile.net/preview/5514229/page:3/) разные вещи...

Вот как это делал бы я:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double f(double x) { return x * x * log10(x) - 3.8; }

int main()
{
    double x0, x1, f0, f1, eps;
    int mt;
    printf("Input x0, xl, epsilon, max itexation\n");
    scanf("%lf %lf %lf %d", &x0, &x1, &eps, &mt);
    f0 = f(x0);
    f1 = f(x1);

    while (fabs(x1 - x0) > eps)
    {
        double x = x1 - f1 * (x1 - x0) / (f1 - f0);
        f0 = f1;
        f1 = f(x);
        x0 = x1;
        x1 = x;

        if (--mt == 0)
        {
            printf("Iterations limit reached; x = %lf\n", x);
            return 0;
        }
    }

    printf("Solution: x = %lf\n", x1);
}
```